# How to change the data of registry property data without knowing the key beforehand

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I'm trying to write code that will find and change the data inside of a registry keys properties if it includes a specific string like 'placeholder'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am addressing the question, how do I search property values in the registry?  The way I do it is with this script:

```
# get-itemproperty2.ps1
# get-childitem skips top level key properties, use get-item for that
param([parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]$key)

process { 
  $valuenames = $key.getvaluenames() 

  if ($valuenames) { 
    $valuenames | foreach {
      $value = $_
      [pscustomobject] @{
        Path = $key -replace 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER',
          'HKCU:' -replace 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE','HKLM:'
        Name = $Value
        Value = $Key.GetValue($Value)
        Type = $Key.GetValueKind($Value)
      }
    }
  } else {
    [pscustomobject] @{
      Path = $key -replace 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER',
        'HKCU:' -replace 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE','HKLM:'
        Name = ''
        Value = ''
        Type = ''
    }
  }
}
```

With that script in hand, here's an example.

```
ls -r hkcu:\key1 | get-itemproperty2 | where value -match value

Path            Name  Value    Type
----            ----  -----    ----
HKCU:\key1\key2 name2 value2 String
```

The results can be used with set-itemproperty.

```
ls -r hkcu:\key1 | get-itemproperty2 | where value -match value | 
  set-itemproperty -value myvalue -whatif
```

Comment: Thanks for your reponse, I'd like to try it but I'm getting this error. 
```Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method named 'GetValueNames'.```
Do you know what may be causing this?

Comment: What are you running exactly?

Comment: I've got it to work just a little user-error. Could you break down the `Get-ItemProperty2` cmdlet a bit for me. I want to understand how it functions. I've tried to use `GetValue, GetValueNames` before to no avail.

Comment: Those methods are only with a RegistryKey type object.  Like:  `$a = get-item hkcu:\key1; $a.gettype()`